# ActivityUnitTestCase and startActivity with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I try to test a Activity which uses ActionBarActivity (from the appcompat library). I need a custom Application to be able to manipulate the DI system to load my test service instead of the real service.

If I have my test written and call startActivity I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

If I call launchActivityWithIntent the Activity starts without any problems but It is using my Real Application class instead of the Mocked Application class. Any ideas how I can fix that or how I can execute code after onCreate of the application was called but before onCreate of my Activity get's called within my instrument test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that if I create a custom MockApplication and add the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
}
```

I hope that will work for other people as well.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem but I couldn't get it to work. Could you share your result?

Comment: Like I said I created a class that extended MockApplication. Then I've overwritten the method onCreate with the snippet above and then I set a instance of that mock application class I've created within the ActivityUnitTestCase class

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer didn't work in my case, but including something this in the ActicityUnitTestCase subclass worked for me:

```
@Override
public void setUp(){
    ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
    setActivityContext(context);
}
```

Comment: do you know how to make this work using roboelectric?

Comment: @AkashRamani did u figure it out for roboelectric? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Remember that we are supposed to create reusable activities and by setting the theme in the onCreate method we are connecting the activity to the AppTheme.

The answer of @Akira Speirs is the best option in my opinion even though we need to remember to update the test if the theme is changed in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity calls setActivity prior to dispatching onCreate so code below does the trick:

```
@Override
protected void setActivity(Activity testActivity) {
    if (testActivity != null) testActivity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.setActivity(testActivity);
}
```

This could be an alternative to solution provided by @Akira Speirs for example if custom context needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was testing a custom component as part of a layout.

Just calling `getActivity().setTheme(...)` in the test's `setUp()` worked for me.

I was also getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926107/getting-instrumentation-run-failed-due-to-java-lang-nullpointerexception) when testing on a real device.

However testing with a API level 23 x86 emulator with HAXM enabled it works and is nice and fast.

Here is a more more complete `setUp()` method as an example:

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    super.setUp();

    startActivity(new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), Activity.class), null, null);

    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.MyAppTheme);

    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_under_test);

}
```