# Theme error using material theme and actionbaractivity

Tags: android, android-theme

I have set up a material theme to be used with Android 5, however I get the below error when trying to run my app:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity

I have looked through my code and seem to have everything in place and really cant find whats wrong,so any help to fixing would be great!

my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

my v21/style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- your app's theme inherits from the Material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary</item>

        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

my Activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    Location location;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("What's in Town");
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            centerMapOnMyLocation();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */

    private void centerMapOnMyLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            drawMarker(location);
        }
    }

    private void drawMarker(Location location) {
        mMap.clear();
        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(currentPosition)
                .snippet("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "Lng:" + location.getLongitude())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .title("ME"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This question already has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: Basically just change extends ActionBarActivity to extends Activity

Comment: possible duplicate of ["You need to use a Theme.Appcompat theme..." when testing ActionBarActivity, but I am](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632169/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-when-testing-actionbaractivity-but)

Comment: `parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"` and `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity` what is not clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity`.