# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme --> in Unit Test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, activityunittestcase

I know this topic has been discussed but it is a little different here:

- App works fine
- Error is displayed only in unit test
- Theme is Fine (new created sample project)

**How to reproduce:**

1. Create just a new project --> FullScreenActivity Android 4.3
2. Create a unit test
3. Run it

   ```
   public class FullscreenActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<FullscreenActivity> {

   public FullscreenActivityTest() {
       super(FullscreenActivity.class);
   }

   public void testStart() {
       startActivity(new Intent(getInstrumentation()
               .getTargetContext(), FullscreenActivity.class), null, null);
       Assert.assertNotNull(getActivity());
   }
   ```

   }

Tested with:

1. Nexus 5 Emulator
2. Nexus 6P Emulator

Each time the same, app works fine. Unit test fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
        at com.sample.foobar.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:163)
```

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Tested now also with a HTC One (5.0.x) same issue here. I can run and use the Activity but not unit test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me -- added to the unit test:

```
@Override
public void setUp(){
    ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
    setActivityContext(context);
}
```

See also:
[ActivityUnitTestCase and startActivity with ActionBarActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364433/activityunittestcase-and-startactivity-with-actionbaractivity)

**Also possible**

Use *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2* instead of *ActivityUnitTestCase* fixes the issue too.

In addition the "onPause" of the activity isn't called. Which is somehow odd with *ActivityUnitTestCase*

Answer (score 2):

Using the new AndroidX libraries this can be solved by passing the theme to the fragment launching method:

```
val authDialogScenario = launchFragment<AuthDialog>(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme)
```

This was the solution in my case.