# Styling issue when using FragmentScenario

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing, android-fragmentscenario

When using `FragmentScenario` from `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` to test fragment UI, not all styles are applied correctly.

As an example, there's very simple application that just presents fragment with following layout:

`fragment_main.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

with default theme generated by Android Studio (4.1.2) that looks like this when running the app:

[image]

doesn't look the same when run as a `FragmentScenario` test:

[image]

I can understand that `ActionBar` is not shown (as it is a part of host `Activity` not a `Fragment`). But **why `Button` is not styled correctly** ...  ??

Comment: Can you look https://stackoverflow.com/a/34480561/13380493. let me know if this fixed the issue

Comment: The Actionbar doesn't appear because FragmentScenario Launches a Fragment with given arguments hosted by an empty FragmentActivity.

Comment: @gawcio i do have the same issue, but in my case, the buttons styled with "style=" in xml disappear completely. Any ideas in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented `FragmentScenario` will launch your `Fragment` in a `EmptyFragmentActivity` (defined within the `FragmentScenario` class) by default this uses the `R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme`.

To ensure our tests use the correct theme we supply our theme `Theme_App` to the `themeResId` param (as well as any Arguments) and it renders correctly.

```
val scenario: FragmentScenario<MyFragment> = launchFragmentInContainer(
            themeResId = style.Theme_App,
            fragmentArgs = args
        )
```